# How to make an address list in mutt

Tags: email, alias, mutt

I use `Mutt` as my main client and use the `alias` command quite frequently.

How to group mail addresses, or—even better—aliases into a list I can then use like an `alias` to send mail to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a file with the following content:

```
alias my_alias1 recipient1@email, recipient1@email
alias my_alias2 recipient3@email, recipient4@email
```

Source it from your mutt config with `source path/to/alias_file`.

[Aliases - Mutt Project Wiki](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MuttGuide/Aliases)

Comment: Whoa, how could I have missed this? It seems it is also possible to use aliases already defined?

Comment: Sure, you can use already defined aliases as targets of another alias.

Answer (score 0):

> `~/myalias.list`:
>
> ```
> alias my_alias1 recipient1@email, recipient1@email, recep3@email.com
> ```

---

> `~/.muttrc`:
>
> ```
> source ~/myalias.list
> ```

I would like to be able to use this alias with `mutt` (`-b` for BCC):

```
$ mutt -b my_alias1
```